# Update Angular 11 : "no such file" on library's css file

Tags: angular

I use ngx-datatable library.

I've imported css files like :

```
@import "~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/index.css";
@import "~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/themes/material.css";
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/assets/icons.css';
```

After angular 11 update, I got following error, for every 3 files :

> ERROR: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> 'C:\Users...\src\tables\component\table-list~@swimlane\ngx-datatable\assets\icons.css'

For both index and material I've switched on .scss file and I do no have error anymore, but there's no icons.scss file.

Any tips?
Thx

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use the angular.json approach better for that.
So, in your angular.json file under "architect" > "build" > "styles" array added them like this:

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.scss",
          {
            "inject":true,
            "input": "./node_modules/swimlane/ngx-datatable/index.css",
            "bundleName": "ngx-datatable-index"
          },
          {
            "inject":true,
            "input": "./node_modules/swimlane/ngx-datatable/themes/material.css",
            "bundleName": "ngx-datatable-material"
          },
          {
            "inject":true,
            "input": "./node_modules/swimlane/ngx-datatable/assets/icons.css",
            "bundleName": "ngx-datatable--icons"
          }
        ]
```